# Will a LEFT JOIN View with GROUP BY inside of it do the right thing?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can I count on SQLite on doing "the right thing (TM)"?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user.Log (
    term TEXT,
    seen DATETIME
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS user.Log_term ON Log(term);
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS user.History AS
SELECT term, COUNT(1) as timesseen, MAX(seen) as lastseen 
FROM user.Log GROUP BY term;
```

And then later

```
INNER JOIN History h ON h.term = t.term
```

Log could be in the 100,000s.  I would like to know if SQLite will pass the h.term = t.term in to the View so that it only groups by terms which match the ON instead of grouping the whole table, and then applying the ON.

If this is a bad idea, a better way is requested.  (Maybe the better way is to keep two tables, the Log and the summarized history.)

Comment: I doubt it.  ...but not 100% sure. What happens when you try it?

Comment: SQLite lets you `EXPLAIN queryname`. Frankly, I find the output really hard to read, but it might be worth loading some test data and running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, a `group by` clause will make a statement lose track of the originating row, so it won't use an index if you constrain your view with a join: you'll read the whole table regardless.

What you need to do is constrain it and *then* group. Avoid aggregate functions in views.